# Why does rails' update_attributes set a param to null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Using update_attributes to update some attributes, I've noticed that one particular attribute gets set to null. How do I overcome it so that I can save the object with it's new value?

```
>> i=Item.find 4940       
#<Item id: 4940, sku: "ASKU", height: <BigDecimal:7fca72343e08,'0.1E3',9(18)>...>
>> i.sku
"ASKU"
>> i.update_attributes(sku: "3232434")
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
false
Item Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `items` WHERE (`items`.`sku` IS NULL AND `items`.`id` != 4940) LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
>> i.sku
nil
>> i.errors.messages.inspect
"{:sku=>[\"can't be blank\", \"is too short (minimum is 3 characters)\"]}"
```

The error seems to be caused by the validation rule that says this param should exist - and it does exist - except when calling update_attributes when it seems to disappear! I've removed the validation rule and it works fine except I now have a blank value where I need a valid value to be.

How do I keep the SKU value and update the object?

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION: The error was being caused by some code I had in the model to ensure the field was upcased. Removing the following fixed everything;

```
def sku=(s)
  super s.upcase!
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being caused by some code I had in the model to ensure the field was upcased. Replacing the following got it working;

```
  def sku=(s)
    super s.upcase!
  end
```

with...

```
  before_validation :upcase_sku

  def upcase_sku
    self.sku.upcase!
  end
```